# react create element to JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am wondering if this is the equivalent in JSX, including both the && operator and the actual writing of createElement to jsx - following the docs here - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

**NO JSX**

```
if(this.props.oldSkool) {
  return (
  <div {...wrapperProps}>
    {labelTop}
    <div {...props} />
    {labelBottom}
  </div>
  )
}
else {
  return null;
}
```

**JSX**

```
 {this.props.oldSkool && (
    <div {...wrapperProps}>
      {labelTop}
      <div {...props} />
      {labelBottom}
    </div>
 )}
```

Comment: You can use the babel website to find out what JSX compiles to: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAFASiQPhgbwFABOAplAK4FgwwA8AJgJYBuuAdGwO4FwAO3RBABQIhuEAL6Y8VKjgA2cAEZFZAFRFip0uk1Ztuw0WJgB6SdNzylsgEIgoUEAFsNVasYaNJYoA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=

Comment: thanks @SebassvanBoxel it looks as if it is a bit off as there is an array for the children but not in your example